# PHP - Getting IP from regex, chat string

Tags: php, regex, string

For simplicity, I have code like this:

```
$n = "Chan"
$str = "2.231.42.3 Eric: ()24.231.23.2 " + $n + ":"
```

What I am trying to do is to sort out the IP by the name, (The IP can be any IP as mentioned in the code below with the {1,3} regex)

What I've tried which is not working:

```
preg_match("/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3} " . $n . "/", $str, $m);
str_replace(" " . $n, "", $m[0], $r);
$ip = $r[0]; // Should return 24.231.23.2, Chan's IP
```

Why isn't my code working and how do you fix this?

Comment: do you want to get ip from this string `)24.231.23.2 Chan`??

Comment: You should check the manual on `str_replace()`; the 4th argument returns the number of replacements made, not an array.

Comment: your code is broken anyways. `+` is mathematical addition in php. `" " + $n` is going to give you an int, not a string.

Comment: Fixed, I do lot's JS that's why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are trying to get IP then this is enough

```
$re = '/(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/'; 
$str = ')24.231.23.2 Chan'; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches)
```

***output***

```
Array ( [0] => 24.231.23.2 [1] => 24.231.23.2 )
```

to match only chan

```
(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}) (?:Chan)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm sorry for not telling you, but it should also work if the string looks like: '2.231.42.3 Eric: ()24.231.23.2 Chan'

Comment: Then it should return Chan's IP

Comment: then just add a space and Chan like this `(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}) Chan`

Comment: add it like this `(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3} Chan)`

Comment: no, it should return "24.231.23.2", not "24.231.23.2 Chan"

Comment: see last line in my answer

Comment: preg_match("/(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}) (?:" . $bn . ")/", $str, $m); $ip = $m[0]; Returns error

Comment: you have to concatenate strings with `.` not with `+` like this
`$str = "2.231.42.3 Eric: ()24.231.23.2 " . $n . ":"`

Comment: I do but it still fails as I said